# running oracle producer with perl

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi, perldb

I used to run normal queries with Perl like (select & insert & update & delete ) with skipping insert semicolon at the end of the query and its working with me, but currently I have to run oracle prouder but as you know the producre sometimes contains N number of the semicolon, any idea about this ?

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsh,$login,$password,{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0} ) or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";
unless($dbh){
warn "Unable to connect to Oracle ($DBI::errstr)\nTests skiped.\n";
print "1..0\n";
exit 0;}
$dbh->do("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'");
print  localtime() ."............ Database connected sucessfully .............\n\n";
$sth2 = $dbh->prepare(" 
DECLARE
   CURSOR coid_to_patch
   IS
        SELECT SIM.CO_ID,
               PADV.SNCODE,
               PADV.ADV_CHARGE,
               SIM.BEFORE_TAX_AMT,
               PADV.ADV_CHARGE_END_DATE,
               PADV.ADV_CHARGE + SIM.BEFORE_TAX_AMT NEW_ADV_CHRG,
               CA.CUSTOMER_ID,
               NVL (CU.CUSTOMER_ID_HIGH, CA.CUSTOMER_ID) CALCULATED_CUSTID,
               TMB1.TMCODE,
               TMB1.VSCODE,
               SIM.MARKET_CODE
          FROM sysadm.SIMULATION_FROM_BSCS_EBLON SIM,
               PROFILE_SERVICE_ADV_CHARGE PADV,
               CUSTOMER_ALL CU,
               CONTRACT_ALL CA,
               MPULKTMB TMB1
         WHERE     SIM.CO_ID = PADV.CO_ID
               AND SIM.CO_STATUS <> 'a'
               AND PADV.ADV_CHARGE > 0
               AND SIM.CO_ID = CA.CO_ID
               AND CA.CUSTOMER_ID = CU.CUSTOMER_ID
               AND CA.TMCODE = TMB1.TMCODE
               AND TMB1.VSCODE = (SELECT MAX (VSCODE)
                FROM MPULKTMB TMB2
                 WHERE TMB2.TMCODE = TMB1.TMCODE)
               AND PADV.SNCODE = TMB1.SNCODE
               AND TMB1.INTERVAL = 12
               AND (PADV.ADV_CHARGE + SIM.BEFORE_TAX_AMT) >= 0
      ORDER BY 6 ASC;
BEGIN
   FOR cur IN coid_to_patch
   LOOP
      UPDATE PROFILE_SERVICE_ADV_CHARGE
         SET ADV_CHARGE = CUR.NEW_ADV_CHRG,
             ADV_CHARGE_ITEM_PRICE = CUR.NEW_ADV_CHRG
       WHERE CO_ID = CUR.CO_ID AND SNCODE = CUR.SNCODE AND ADV_CHARGE > 0;

      COMMIT;
      dbms_output.put_line (
            'Refund terminated for CoId: '
         || CUR.CO_ID
         || ' on Sncode : '
         || CUR.SNCODE);
   END LOOP;
END;
")or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth2->execute() or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sth2->finish;
print localtime() ."..........Closed..........\n\n";
$dbh->commit;
$dbh->disconnect;
exit;
```

Comment: I believe this is a possible duplicate. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232950/perl-dbi-run-sql-script-with-multiple-statements).