# Perl SQL::SplitStatement hangs on large string

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

Debian-9.11 x86, perl-5.24, SQL::SplitStatement-1.0020

There's 23 Mb MySQL-file with several `REPLACE INTO ... VALUES(...)` one command per file line. All strings are valid SQL. But one string is about 8 mln chars.

When trying to parse it through `SQL::SplitStatement` (see below), script hangs, eating 100% CPU and does nothing as a result.

```
my $sql_blob=read_file("$INDIR/$f",{binmode => ':utf8'});
my $sql_splitter= SQL::SplitStatement->new();
my @sql_list=$sql_splitter->split($sql_blob); print "Size: $#sql_list\n"; # This will be never printed
```

What's wrong? Bug?

Comment: Seems like `SQL::SplitStatement` uses [`SQL::Tokenizer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Tokenizer) to split the SQL code into statements. The tokenizer uses [a simple Perl regex](https://metacpan.org/release/SQL-Tokenizer/source/lib/SQL/Tokenizer.pm#L16) (no real parser). Such a long statement as you have might indeed be to heavy for it.. Can you try to reduce the `$sql_blob` to only the long statement? Does it still hang?

Comment: Reduced input file for `$sql_blob` to one long-long line with REPLACE INTO (...) VALUES (...), (...), ... (...); - same result - hangs up on `split($sql_blob)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tested `DBIx:RunSQL->split_sql` - it doesn't split SQLs in one-line at all. `SQL::SplitStatement` even on core-i7 with 16 Gb RAM eats 2 CPU cores and does nothing...

Found answer here: [Perl DBI - run SQL Script with multiple statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232950/perl-dbi-run-sql-script-with-multiple-statements/1233003#1233003) -
subroutine seems to work for my tasks - it splits string like `SQL1 (?,?) VALUES (?,?);SQL2 <some_statement>;SQL3;` into separate SQL commands. Also it works OK with long lines (more than 8 mln and several SQL commands in this line).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that statement is just too large for the module? Here is an alternative you can try: [C++ SQL Parser](https://github.com/hyrise/sql-parser). I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <hsql/SQLParser.h>

int main()
{
    const std::string query = R"##(SELECT * FROM foo where a =  1; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a == 2; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a != 1; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a <> 1; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a >  1; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a <  1; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a >= 1; 
            SELECT * FROM foo where a <= 1; 
        SELECT * FROM foo where a = TRUE; 
        SELECT * FROM foo where a = false;)##";
    hsql::SQLParserResult result;
    hsql::SQLParser::parse(query, &result);

    if (result.isValid() && result.size() > 0) {
        auto num_statements = result.size();
        std::cout << "Number of statements: " << num_statements << '\n';
        for (int i=0; i< num_statements ; i++) {
            const hsql::SQLStatement* statement = result.getStatement(i);
            if (statement->isType(hsql::kStmtSelect)) {
                const hsql::SelectStatement* select
                    = (const hsql::SelectStatement*) statement;
                std::cout << " " << i << ": SELECT statement\n";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "parse failed: " << result.errorMsg() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Number of statements: 10
 0: SELECT statement
 1: SELECT statement
 2: SELECT statement
 3: SELECT statement
 4: SELECT statement
 5: SELECT statement
 6: SELECT statement
 7: SELECT statement
 8: SELECT statement
 9: SELECT statement
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll look closer to module, you've posted. Yes, maybe statement is too long, but SQL::SplitStatement says nothing about such limitations. Also `perl -d <script> seems to give infinite loop somewhere in  "native" perl subroutines, like `split`.